# How to set the parameter virtual host on deploymnet.toml rabbitMQ/WSO2 IE

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2

Hi there I want to make a consumer service on WSO2 and I found this documentation about the configuration of wso2 deploymnet.toml file [documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/config-catalog/#rabbitmq-listener), But there is nothing about vhost parameter there and I have a vhost on the rabbitMQ clouster so I need to set this value, any one  knows how to do it ? Thanks in advnace

I already tried this but it did no work

```
 parameter.vhost = "vhost_vlaue"
```

Here is the error that I receive when my service start, and is because my user only has access to one vhost

```
connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=530, reply-text=NOT_ALLOWED - access to vhost '/' refused for user 'qzwzitby', class-id=10, method-id=40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no parameter mapping for virtual host, in deployment.toml.

BUT you can set that, when you define RabbitMQ Inbound as `rabbitmq.server.virtual.host`, like below:

```
<inboundEndpoint name="test.rabbitmq" onError="fault" protocol="rabbitmq" sequence="from.rabbitmq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<parameters>
    <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
    ... 
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.virtual.host">myVirtualHost</parameter>
</parameters>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much men I was in this error during whole day and I just to fix it by using your example